# Damaged adjustable threshold

Tags: doors, threshold

The rubber seal? on the outside of threshold got damaged when our dog got locked in the garage. Is there a way to replace the seal w/o replacing the entire threshold?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to disassemble the threshold and remove the top piece. From there, look for a brand or manufacturer name and contact them. You can also take the piece to your home store and try to match the rubber strip or get something close. Those strips usually slide into a groove on the threshold.

Comment: An end-on picture of the (intact part of) the weatherstriping and image search might be most productive.